# Dense line on complex torus

Tags: complex-geometry, integer-lattices

Let $L\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a lattice of rank $2n$ and $v\in \mathbb{C}^n$. Is there a characterization when the set

$$ \{ z v \in \mathbb{C}^n/L \ : \ z \in \mathbb{C} \} $$

lies dense in $\mathbb{C}^n/L$?

In the real case we have for $(w_1, \cdots, w_{2n})=w\in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ that

$$ \{ x w \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}/\mathbb{Z}^{2n} \ : \ x \in \mathbb{R} \} $$

lies dense in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}/\mathbb{Z}^{2n}$ iff the $w_i$ do not fulfill a relation of the form

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{2n} m_j \cdot \omega_j \in \mathbb{Z} $$

for $(m_1, \dots, m_n)\in \mathbb{Z}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$. By transforming the lattice, one gets for a general lattice $L\subset \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ that

$$ \{ x w \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}/L \ : \ x \in \mathbb{R} \} $$

lies dense in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}/L$ iff the $w_i$ do not fulfill a relation of the form

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{2n} m_j \cdot \omega_j \in L $$

for $(m_1, \dots, m_n)\in \mathbb{Z}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

I was hoping that there is a similar statement in the complex case for a general lattice. I.e. is it true that

$$ \{ z v \in \mathbb{C}^n/L \ : \ z \in \mathbb{C} \} $$

lies dense in $\mathbb{C}^n/L$ iff the $v_i$ do not fulfill a relation of the form

$$ \sum_{j=1}^{n} m_j \cdot v_j \in L $$

for $(m_1, \dots, m_n)\in \mathbb{Z}^n \setminus \{ 0 \}$?

In fact, I would already be glad if there was a characterization in the case, when the lattice is of the form

$$ L= \langle e_1, \dots, e_n, \tau_1, \dots, \tau_n \rangle $$

where, $e_i\in \mathbb{C}^n$ denotes the $i$th standard basis vector and the matrix

$$ \tau = \begin{pmatrix} \tau_1 \dots \tau_n 
\end{pmatrix} \in Mat(n\times n, \mathbb{C})$$

is symmetric with positive definite imaginary part.

Comment: Do you want $\mathbb{C}^n/\mathbb{Z}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}^n/\mathbb{Z}[i]^n$?

Comment: @AlfredYerger I tried to explain better, what I want to know.

Comment: Does the proof for the real case statement truly use that the lattice is the standard basis one, or does it go over for any lattice?

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon In the real case there is no problem with the lattice, we can just use a linear transformation to reduce to the integer lattice. In the complex case, it's not so clear to me, whether this works, as transforming the lattice will in general not respect the complex structure.

Comment: Right, but do we reduce to that case just for convenience or to avoid lattice terminology, or is there something specific in that proof that relies on it being exactly that lattice?

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon I mainly reduced to the integer lattice, as I can then apply Kronecker's Approximation Theorem, which gives me the desired statement. In fact it even tells me that $$\{ m v \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}/\mathbb{Z}^{2n} : m\in \mathbb{Z} \}$$ lies dense in the torus (by transforming this holds again for every lattice). My feeling is, that the lattice should not be too relevant in my question. The main problem I see is the transition from the real to the complex numbers. Maybe I completely misunderstood your question.

Comment: No, I see. It was me who was misunderstanding things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compact topological abelian group is $G=\mathbb{C}^n/L$. Want to know whether the closure $\bar M$ of a certain set $M$ ($M$ closed under addition) is the whole group $G$ (apriori $\bar M$ is just a semigroup, but because of the compactness of $G$ it is a subgroup). Here is the criterion: $\bar M= G$ if an only the only character of $G$ that is $1$ on $M$ is the trivial character.

The characters of $G$ are $$\phi_k \colon x \mapsto \exp(2\pi i k \cdot x)$$ where $k\in \hat L$, the dual lattice of $L$. With the above criterion, we can say: $\mathbb{C} \cdot v$ is not closed in $\mathbb{C}/L$ if and only if there exists $k \in \hat L$, $k\ne 0$ so that 
$$k \cdot v = 0 \\ k \cdot (iv) = 0$$ ( $\cdot $ the usual dot product).

Let's consider the particular case $L=\mathbb{Z}^n$. The above equalities mean: there exists $(u_1, \ldots, u_n)\in \mathbb{Z}[i]^n$ not all $0$ so that $\sum u_i v_i = 0$

So, for instance, the line $\mathbb{C}\cdot v$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}^2/\mathbb{Z}^4$ if and only if the ratio of the components of $v$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.